# Calling upon a locally defined variable later on python

Tags: python-3.x, local-variables

I am trying to recall upon these locally defined variables (p1,p2,w1,w2) later on outside. In my program I made it so if the user inputted something other than a number the program would prompt the user that they incorrectly inputted their response. However, this caused my variables to defined locally and I am unaware of how to use those locally defined variables later on. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

```
fp=input("\nWhat percentage do you want to finish the class with?")


def main():
    p1 = get_number("\nWhat is your 1st marking period percentage? ")
    w1 = get_number("\nWhat is the weighting of the 1st marking period? ")
    p2 = get_number("\nWhat is your 2nd marking period percentage? ")
    w2 = get_number("\nWhat is the weighting of the 2nd marking period? ")


def get_number(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            text = input(prompt)
        except EOFError:
            raise SystemExit()
        else:
            try:
                number = float(text)
            except ValueError:
                print("Please enter a number.")
            else:
                break
    return number


def calculate_score(percentages, weights):
    if len(percentages) != len(weights):
        raise ValueError("percentages and weights must have same length")
    return sum(p * w for p, w in zip(percentages, weights)) / sum(weights)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


mid=input("\nDid your have a midterm exam? (yes or no)")
if mid=="yes":
    midg=input("\nWhat was your grade on the midterm?")
    midw=input("\nWhat is the weighting of the midterm exam?")
elif mid=="no":
    midw=0
    midg=0
fw=input("\nWhat is the weighting of the final exam? (in decimal)")


fg=(fp-(w1*p1)-(w2*p2)-(midw*midg))/(fw)
print("You will need to get a", fg ,"on your final to finish the class with a", fp)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to pass variables from scope to scope is to `return` them from your function:

```
def main():
    p1 = get_number("\nWhat is your 1st marking period percentage? ")
    w1 = get_number("\nWhat is the weighting of the 1st marking period? ")
    p2 = get_number("\nWhat is your 2nd marking period percentage? ")
    w2 = get_number("\nWhat is the weighting of the 2nd marking period? ")

    return p1, w1, p2, w2
```

Then, when you call the `main` function, assign that function's outputs to the appropriate names:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    p1, w1, p2, w2 = main()
```

Note that you don't have to call them `p1`, `w1`, `p2`, and `w2` at this stage—you can assign them to whatever names make sense in the scope you're working in.  That's the power of dividing things into functions—outside the function, you don't have to worry about following the same naming convention that's used inside the function (which you may not even know). You could also assign/refer to the four outputs together as a `tuple`, i.e. call:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    numbers = main()
```

and subsequently refer to them as `numbers[0]`, `numbers[1]`, `numbers[2]` and `numbers[3]`.